# Is the genre "reality television" partitioned into the sub-genres "factual" and "scripted reality"?

Tags: terminology, genre

> **Reality television** is a genre of television programming that documents purportedly unscripted real-life situations, often starring unknown individuals rather than professional actors.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Reality_television&oldid=909623404)

> **Factual television** is a genre of non-fiction television programming that documents actual events and people.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Factual_television&oldid=903855628)

> **Scripted reality** [...] is a subgenre of reality television with some or all of the contents being scripted or pre-arranged by the production company.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Scripted_reality&oldid=902683737)

It is pretty clear that scripted reality and factual television are mutually exclusive - a show cannot be both at the same time. An example for factual television is [Highway Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_Patrol_(Australian_TV_series)), an example for scripted reality is [Lenßen & Partner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len%C3%9Fen_%26_Partner).

Is there any show / series / movie which belongs to the genre "reality tv", but is neither factual nor scripted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, yes. But it boils down to borders of "actual events and people". For some Jersey Shore/Big Brother and similar would not be factual television because the TV show was the reason everything you see is happening. People live in close space, have excess of money or alcohol or any other thing and their actions is driven by certain desired outcome known before the shooting. Again, some may argue that it fall into "scripted".
Second thing is what other benchmarks you are using. For example, in Europe (and UK) factual television (or documentaries) require specific type of narration, commentary and/or preface. So History Channel production with dramatic cuts, pre-recorded commentary would not be categorized as Factual but scripted.

Comment: "History Channel production with dramatic cuts, pre-recorded commentary would not be categorized as Factual but scripted" - interesting! Thank you!